# Ingesting multiple timestamps of the same metric?

Tags: prometheus

I have data stored in a SQL database that I want to replicate into prometheus for its better capabilities in handling time series data.

However, I am still wondering what the best way is to expose that data to prometheus.

What I tried is exposing a document like this:

```
# TYPE energy_amount_watt_hours counter
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="A",type="generator"} 8275866 1529787904
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="B",type="grid_import"} 681113 1529787903
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="C",type="generator"} 4201804 1529787903
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="D",type="grid_import"} 6209100 1529787612
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="E",type="grid_export"} 9554800 1529787612
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="A",type="generator"} 8275866 1529787606
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="C",type="generator"} 4201804 1529787605
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="F",type="grid_import"} 1216300 1529787602
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="B",type="grid_import"} 681093 1529787602
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="A",type="generator"} 8275866 1529787305
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="C",type="generator"} 4201804 1529787304
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="B",type="grid_import"} 681073 1529787303
energy_amount_watt_hours{meter="A",type="generator"} 8275866 1529787004
```

So basically exposing multiple values for each metric but with different timestamps. However, that fails with out of bounds errors for me (which is irritating). Reading the documentation I see that:

> Each line must have a unique combination of metric name and labels. Otherwise, the ingestion behavior is undefined.

So this is probably why I receive those unexpected errors.

The question remains: How would I be able to store data in prometheus that originates from a SQL storage. Especially:

- the time of the sample is not now
- I might have multiple samples per metric/label combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus's aggregation model doesn't seem to support this. It simply ingests whatever it receives from the scrape and adds a timestamp of the instant the scrape took place.

I didn't realize this and ran into some odd behaviour with histograms, expecting that each data point I added to the histogram object in the client library would have the timestamp of that event attached, and then the scraper was just grabbing all of these data points, preserving their timestamps. Not so.

Consider the scrape like a measurement, or a sample, of your system at the exact moment the scrape occurs.